# Upgrade to Visual Studio 2013 from 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I was wondering if someone could provide some guidance.

Can I use the VS2013 Upgrade path to upgrade my VS2010 to 2013  - or do you need to go to 2012 first?

thanks

Comment: There is no "path".  It is just another program, completely independent from 2010.  No need for 2012.

Comment: thanks for the response - my question really is if I purchase the $99 VS2013 Upgrade - will it let me install - because I have VS2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of things you can only use the $99 special to upgrade from VS2012 pro

http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2013/10/17/visual-studio-2013-professional-upgrade-only-for-99-for-a-limited-time.aspx

Comment: that's what I thought too - but wanted to validate... thanks Fanie

Comment: Only a pleasure. Remember you can also choose from the Visual Studio Express range depending on your scenario and requirements. http://forums.wpcentral.com/developers-corner/248434-vs-2013-vs-vs-express.html

Answer (score 3):

You can go straight to Visual Studio 2013 as it fully supports round tripping from VS 2010

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/06/04/vs-2013-round-tripping.aspx

Comment: He's asking about the cost involved, not the compatibility of project and solution files.

Comment: Actually, it did address the question.  You're thinking of one of the comments that came AFTER this answer was posted (and the question was not even edited to reflect the clarification), so the -1 was not justified.